# Laravel 5 OAuth2

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, laravel-5

I've been trying all day to setup the OAuth2 for Laravel 5 without success. I am creating a REST API which will be connected with mobile devices and give to them data if authenticated as users and get the corresponding data.

I have installed in my project the package of lucadegasperi which is located:

https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel

Truth is that I do not understand how to implement it since I cannot find a detail documentation.

The api that I am creating will be able to create new users, login and give them data that are authorized to view.

I do not understand how to setup the access token when registering a user.
Also, should the clients send the access token back through headers?

Right now, I am trying to create my own authorization system where when the user will be created I will generate a Token and return in to the client. So the next time the client will try to get data from the server to send that token instead of username/password. Is that correct?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Mobile web or for an app?

Comment: For an app. Also I forgot to mention that I am trying to implement the password grant_type

Comment: I would look at a standard php implantation on facebooks page for oauth. Then using the auth login call on latavel to login users manually